# Row of the Summer

Tags: figures-of-speech, politics

Those following the "Brexit" politics in the U.K. probably have heard David Davis (U.K. Chief Negotiator) characterize the negotiations ahead as the *row of the summer*. I'm a continental European and can only guess what it means. Can someone explain this figure of speech? Here's some context:

From an [article in The Irish Independent](http://www.independent.ie/world-news/and-finally/david-daviss-predicted-row-of-the-summer-over-the-brexit-negotiations-timetable-didnt-exactly-last-long-35846108.html) with the headline

**David Davis's predicted 'row of the summer' over the Brexit negotiations timetable didn't exactly last long**

> The Brexit negotiations suffered a pretty embarrassing setback yesterday over timetabling.
>
> Brexit Secretary David Davis had wanted trade talks to take place in parallel with negotiations on the divorce bill from Brussels and had previously warned that the dispute would be “the row of the summer”.
>
> But on day one, the UK ended up agreeing to a different Brexit timetable set out by the European Commission’s chief negotiator, Michel Barnier, meaning those important trade talks will have to wait.

Comment: Note that there are several distinct words spelled "row".  The one you want isn't even pronounced the same as in "row your boat".

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed so! For the spelling *row*, the OED attests no fewer than 18 different words! I don't mean merely different senses of the same word, but rather 18 completely separate headwords (just like *bow* can be something you tie on a package or something a man does instead of a curtsey). These 18 different *row* words amount to 7 nouns, 8 verbs, 2 adjectives, and 1 adverb. Of the 18, only 5 are marked as no longer in contemporary use; the other 13 are still used currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading British English. Note

> the **dispute** would be “the **row** of the summer”.

Here, *dispute* and *row* are synonyms.

**Row** (3)

> *British, informal*
>
> 1 A noisy acrimonious quarrel.
>
> 1.1 A serious dispute.

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/row#row_Noun_300))

Note this word is pronounced /raʊ/, rhyming with *cow*.

The phrase "the row/dispute of the summer" means, broadly,  *the really big/important  row/dispute that will occur/has incurred over the summer that everyone will remember because every other row/dispute of the same summer doesn't have the same significance*.

Comment: The word is known in US English as well.